# Flash AS3 How to display a random item from an xml list then remove that item from the list so it will not be reused

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm using Flash AS3 trying to display random questions from an xml list on stage. When the user clicks an option it should move on to another question but the one they got should be removed from the list so it will not come back.
I have the randomize part okay but can't figure out how to remove the question from the list.
Here is the section I have.

```
function randomizeQuestion():void {
    var numOfQuestions:Number = xmlData.item.length();
    var shuffledNumbers:Array = new Array(randomAns.length);
    var randomPos:Number = 0;

    //Randomizes selected question
    currentQuestion = int(Math.random() * numOfQuestions);

    //Randomizes answer numbers
    for (var i:int = 0; i < shuffledNumbers.length; i++)
    {
        randomPos = int(Math.random() * randomAns.length);
        shuffledNumbers[i] = randomAns.splice(randomPos, 1)[0];
    }

    randomAns = shuffledNumbers;

    correctAns = xmlData.item[currentQuestion].children().(hasOwnProperty("@correct"));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to get index:

```
correctAnsIndex = xmlData.item[currentQuestion].children().(hasOwnProperty("@correct")).childIndex();
```

or if more elements, to get first one:

```
correctAnsIndex = xmlData.item[currentQuestion].children().(hasOwnProperty("@correct"))[0].childIndex();
```

then use delete where appropriate, like here:

```
delete xmlData.item[correctAnsIndex];
```

Comment: I've been trying to implement your suggestions here @Nemi but I'm probably doing it wrong because my code just gets buggy with different typeErrors. Do I need to give you more specifics?

Comment: Does your code has errors without this? Can you update your question with the code you used?

Answer (score 2):

I would add another array to your code in which you can store all the questions that are eligible. As a question gets asked, remove it from that array. So you'll have one array of allQuestions and another array of eligibleQuestions. `allQuestions` can just be a comprehensive list.  Then, push all the questions you want to go through into the `eligibleQuestions` array. As the questions get answered, splice them from the array.

Answer (score 2):

It would be good to also share an example of your XML file that you're loading, but let's use the example below.

```
<data>
    <item>
         <question></question>
         <option1></option1>
         <option2></option2>
    </item>
    <item>
         <question></question>
         <option1></option1>
         <option2></option2>
    </item>
</data>
```

Based on the code you have, I assume your function is being called each time you want to randomize a question.

Now what you'd want to do is create an array that holds the number of `<item>` tags you have outside of this function so that you can remove values from it whenever you want.

You can create this `var numOfQuestions:Array = new Array();` as a global variable and then initialize it using a loop before you enter the `randomizeQuestions()` function.

```
for(var i = 0; i < xmlData['item'].length(); i++)
{
    numOfQuestions.push(i);
}
```

Basically this array will serve as a method of calling a specific item and removing it from the program without altering the actual XML file in any way.

Then whenever you wish to remove an element you use

`numOfQuestions.splice(numOfQuestions.indexOf(valueToBeRemoved), 1);`

This will search the array for the element you wish to remove and then remove it from the array.

Lastly the `randomizeQuestion` function has to be modified.

- `currentQuestion = int(Math.random() * numOfQuestions.length); //since numOfQuestions is now an array instead of a Number`

Comment: I have tried this thing in several ways and it seems I'm missing something somewhere. I've also tried the suggestions from @Neal but since I'm not so good at this I'm just not getting ahead. Can any of you give me a little more details that may help? Remember I'm a novice so I'm probably not doing something right.

Comment: What happens is that it only displays the first question and no more. It doesn't seem to be getting all the questions.

Comment: Changing the second part of the for loop to read `i < xmlData['item'].length()` should fix the problem.